# R - color scatterplot points by z value with legend

Tags: r

I have a scatterplot and wish to color the points by a `z` value assigned to each point. Then I want to get the legend on the right hand side of the plot to show what colors correspond to what `z` values using a nice smooth color spectrum.

Here are some `x,y,z` values you can use so that this is a reproducible example.

```
x = runif(50)
y = runif(50)
z = runif(50) #determines color of the (x,y) point
```

I suppose the best answer would be one that is generalized for any color function, but I do anticipate using `rainbow()`

Comment: How can I move it to Stack Overflow?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181653/creating-a-more-continuous-color-palette-in-r-ggplot2-lattice-or-latticeextra).

Comment: I found a similar question [here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472135/how-do-i-make-a-color-spectrum-legend-which-represents-my-z-values) I was able to reproduce the answer and it looks very nice. Check it out.

Comment: We've migrated it for you, @StanLe. You might check out the linked threads. GL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use ggplot2 I modified a solution to this provided by someone else, I don't remember who.

```
scatter_fill <- function (x, y, z,xlim=c(min(x),max(x)),ylim=c(min(y),max(y)),zlim=c(min(z),max(z)),
                          nlevels = 20, plot.title, plot.axes, 
                          key.title, key.axes, asp = NA, xaxs = "i", 
                          yaxs = "i", las = 1, 
                          axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, ...) 
{
  mar.orig <- (par.orig <- par(c("mar", "las", "mfrow")))$mar
  on.exit(par(par.orig))
  w <- (3 + mar.orig[2L]) * par("csi") * 2.54
  layout(matrix(c(2, 1), ncol = 2L), widths = c(1, lcm(w)))
  par(las = las)
  mar <- mar.orig
  mar[4L] <- mar[2L]
  mar[2L] <- 1
  par(mar = mar)

# choose colors to interpolate
levels <- seq(zlim[1],zlim[2],length.out = nlevels)
col <- colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","dark green"))(nlevels)  
colz <- col[cut(z,nlevels)]  
#   
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = range(levels), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")

rect(0, levels[-length(levels)], 1, levels[-1L],col=col,border=col) 
if (missing(key.axes)) {if (axes){axis(4)}}
       else key.axes
   box()
   if (!missing(key.title)) 
     key.title
   mar <- mar.orig
   mar[4L] <- 1
   par(mar = mar)

   # points
   plot(x,y,type = "n",xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab="",ylab="",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,bty="n")
   points(x,y,col = colz,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab="",ylab="",bty="n",...)

   ## options to make mapping more customizable

        if (missing(plot.axes)) {
          if (axes) {
            title(main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "")
            Axis(x, side = 1)
            Axis(y, side = 2)
          }
        }
        else plot.axes
        if (frame.plot) 
          box()
        if (missing(plot.title)) 
          title(...)
        else plot.title
        invisible()
 }
```

Just run the function first and it is ready to be used. It is quite handy.

```
# random vectors
vx <- rnorm(40,0,1)
vy <- rnorm(40,0,1)
vz <- rnorm(40,10,10)

scatter_fill(vx,vy,vz,nlevels=15,xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,5),zlim=c(-10,10),main="TEST",pch=".",cex=8)
```

As you can notice, it inherits the usual plot function capabilities.

[image]

Comment: Could you modify this so that I can set the zlim?

Comment: When I run your code, I'm getting: Error in scatter_fill(allX, allY, allZ, nlevels = 15, main = "TEST", pch = ".",  : 
  attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Did you run the scatter_fill function beforehand? It must me loaded in the workspace before you can use it.

Comment: Yes I did, I just stuck all the code in the same file. Exactly as you've listed it above. And I even added an rm(list=ls(all=T)) at the very top. Seems to be an error in the code. What does this error even mean? Any ideas?

Comment: Works! Except...How about adding a xlim, ylim, and zlim paramater? Could you add that?

Comment: Why do you want it? it already takes into consideration the maximum and minimum value you feed into z. If you want to truncate that you can just do it from your original data. In the function you can choose to include the axes, the colors to use, etc. Let me see... check my edit. Greetings.

Comment: Ok... I added a zlim parameter, if you dont provide any info for this it will just take the max/min as before. I hope this works for you. Greetings. By the way if you uncomment the lines at the end of the function (aprox. 42 to 51) you get your axes plotted.

Comment: Also added xlim and ylim.

Comment: is this great! @JEquihua why cant you make a multipanel plots of these? Getting error: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: @Megan even if you beforehand do: graphics.off() ?

Answer (score 6):

Translated from [this previous question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472135/how-do-i-make-a-color-spectrum-legend-which-represents-my-z-values)

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=runif(50),y=runif(50),z=runif(50))
ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = z), shape = 19)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative using `levelplot` in package `latticeExtra`, with three different colour palettes.

```
library(latticeExtra)
levelplot(z ~ x + y, panel = panel.levelplot.points, col.regions = heat.colors(50))
levelplot(z ~ x + y, panel = panel.levelplot.points,
  col.regions =colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn"))(50))
levelplot(z ~ x + y, panel = panel.levelplot.points, col.regions = rainbow(50))
```

[image]